# Does an ajax request done by a timer extend the session?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

In my Asp.Net MVC application, I want to hide the cart and some buttons if the session is expired.

Here is what I found to do that : [How to call function on timer ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329859/how-to-call-function-on-timer-asp-net-mvc)

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  // Send an AJAX request every 5s to poll for changes and update the UI
  // example with jquery:
  $.get('/foo', function(result) {
    // TODO: use the results returned from your controller action
    // to update the UI
  });
}, 5000);
```

The question is about the effect of this type of ajax calls on the session. **Will an ajax call like this extend the session or as it is not an user action, the session will expire at the end ?**

Comment: Yes, sending the request will extend the session, so this pattern is flawed.

Comment: I don't know if I should ask another question. In this case, is there any way to check if the session is expired periodicly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877646/handler-with-irequiressessionstate-does-not-extend-session-timeout It seems that you can remove this functionality by removing a header. But im not sure what header since the OP of the linked question removes all.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I am going to try your article. And I found this : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/457540/Redirect-to-Session-Expired-Page-When-Session-time I will update my question if I find a solution.

Comment: If you find a solution, don't update your _question_. Instead, write the solution in the _answers_ section of the page. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was what I wanted to say but I couldn't be clear :) Thanks. I am going to post the solution as answer if I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the soulution:

Added this class in my appication :

```
   using System;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using System.Web.Security;

namespace Capron.MVC.Filters
{
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
   public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower() == "home" 
            && (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower() == "index" 
            || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower() == "ındex")) {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if (sessionCookie != null && sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
                }
            }
        }
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
   }
}
```

And added this attribute to my controller:

```
[SessionExpireFilterAttribute]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
 ...
```